# How to test DRF serializer when using additional keyword arguments?

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-rest-framework, python-unittest

I have a simple model and a serializer which uses additional keyword arguments(extra_kwargs) to limit max and min value for a field. I want to write two test cases in my tests.py to both test valid and invalid values for that field (weight). How should I do this?
I am using Python 2.7.

**Model**

```
from django.db import models

class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    weight = models.FloatField()
```

**Serializer**

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import Person

class PersonSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    model = Person
    fields = ('name', 'weight')
    extra_kwargs = {'weight': {'min_value': 5, 'max_value': 1000}}
```

**tests.py**

```
from django.test import TestCase
from .models import Person

class ModelTestCase(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.person = Person(name='Sam', weight=150)

    def test_when_weight_isValid(self):
        #e.g. when weight = 200

    def test_when_weight_notValid(self):
        #e.g. when weight = 3
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import json

from django.urls import reverse
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate
from rest_framework import status
from rest_framework.test import APITestCase

from .models import *


class UserTests(APITestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.person = Person(name='Sam', weight=150)

    def test_when_weight_isvalid(self):
        url = reverse('person-detail', kwargs={'pk': self.person.id})
        data = {'weight': 200}
        response = self.client.patch(url, data, format='json')
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, status.HTTP_200_OK)
        print json.dumps(response.data, ensure_ascii=False, indent=2)
```

Something like this,code is untest.

Comment: I was wondering how I could test it without using request and response. Is there a way to do this without importing "APITestCase" and importing "TestCase" instead?

Comment: first it's no,and it's not a really request,you can  run test without you server on.